# View creation with a prepared statement in While seems not work properly

Tags: mysql, while-loop, view, prepared-statement

I have a stored procedure which has a While, and in this While, I need to create a view from a dynamic SQL statement.
For the first iteration, my view contains good result but followinf iterations have always the primary result and not rows corresponding to the new prepared statement...

If I replace a WHILE by 2x the create view with differents values of @a, results are as expected.
The prepared statement on a While seems to be a problem...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bug;
DELIMITER | 
CREATE PROCEDURE bug()
BEGIN
   DECLARE a INT(1);
   DECLARE s VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';

   SET @a = 1;

   WHILE @a <= 2 DO

      SET @s = concat('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bugview as SELECT ',@a,';');

      select concat('@s=',@s);

      PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

      select @a;
      select * from bugview;

      set @a = @a + 1;
   END WHILE;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

The wrong result (on the last table, the value expected should be 2 and not 1) :

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| concat('@s=',@s)                               |
+------------------------------------------------+
| @s=CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bugview as SELECT 1; |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+
| @a   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+------------------------------------------------+
| concat('@s=',@s)                               |
+------------------------------------------------+
| @s=CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bugview as SELECT 2; |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+------+
| @a   |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Interesting, what happens if you change 2 to 3 in the while condition?

Comment: Some news about my issue...

Problem is not related to the prepare statement in a While but it seems to be related to the SELECT from the View in a While...
Because the content of the View is correct for all iterations, but when I do the select * from bugview I have only the result from the first iteration...

Do you have an explanation for this please ?

Comment: Hi Nae,
I have the same result with <=3 as condition.
The result for SELECT * FROM bugview is always 1...

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `SELECT VERSION();` and `SHOW CREATE VIEW bugview;` _after_ the sp is run?

Comment: Version :

    5.5.25a-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log

Comment: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`jsmon`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `bugview` AS select 3 AS `3`

Comment: So, my only solution is to upgrade to mysql 5.7 ?

Comment: I'd not assume so. Try calling another prepared statement for the select perhaps?

Comment: Great idea Nae !!
I've moved the select on a stored procedure, and all is OK now !
For your information, I've tried the previous code in mysql v10 and I've always the same issue
Thanks a lot for your help  :)